# How to extract an ISO file and then repack it back into a working ISO file?

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, iso

**What do I want to do?**

I want to extract ISO file and edit the files in it then repack it back into an ISO file. (As you have already read)

**Why do I want to do that?**

I wanna start modding PSP ISOs and for this I have to play with the games resources, assets and everything. But for doing so I have to extract the ISO of the game, edit the files and then repack the files back into an ISO (that should of course run).

**What I request from you guys?**

Please tell me how to do so. I want to mod Dragon Ball PSP games for myself (I might also share the mods throughout the internet).

**On What platform am I working?**

I can use Windows 10, Ubuntu (VM) and Android 8

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try **UMDGen** For Patching,Repacking,Etc. PSP ISOs.
https://downzen.com/en/windows/umdgen/